# Contract killed but receive Ether

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am with a doubt about the function **selfdestruct** in solidity. I have this contract below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

 contract TestMetamask {

 string public name = "Joao";
 event EtherReceived();

 function changeName(string _name) public {
    name = _name;
 }

 function() public payable {
    emit EtherReceived();
 }

 function receiveEther() payable public {
    address(this).transfer(msg.value);
 }

 function balance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
 }

 function kill() public {
    selfdestruct(msg.sender);
 }
}
```

So this contract works, but when I execute the function kill() the contract keeps getting receiving ether in the function payable **receiveEther**.
The another functions doesn't works and the state variables are clean, the problem is only with the contract destructed receive ether.

This is the address of the contract at rinkeby:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xe0491e86b972ae4b0f8359a6066b79256ea01274

Does anyone has been the same situation?

tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selfdestructing, it's still possible to send ether to the contract, which will be lost forever.
See this stackexchange question as well: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46813/what-is-happening-after-a-self-destruct-is-called-for